# php does not save data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Attached below is my PHP code. Table `mylibrary` contains isbn and title record. The PHP script cannot connect to mysql. Why ?

```
<?php
$conn_error = 'Could not connect.';
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_pass = '';
$mysql_db='b_database';

if(!@mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user,$mysql_pass)|| !@mysql_select_db($mysql_db)){
  die($conn_error);

}
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Php Code for View, Search, Edit and Delete Record" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Add Student Record</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1><u>Library Database</u></h1>
</center>
<?
if($_POST["do"]=="store")
{
$isbn=$_POST["isbn"];
$title=$_POST["title"];
if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
  $query="insert into mylibrary value
  ('$isbn','$title')";
  mysql_query($query);
  echo "Successfully store in DATABASE";
  }
  ?>
  <form name="add" method="post" action="add.php">
  <table style=" border:1px solid silver" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0px"
  align="center" border="0">
  <tr>
  <td colspan="4" style="background:#0066FF; color:#FFFFFF; fontsize:
  20px">ADD RECORD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Enter ISBN</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="isbn" size="20"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Enter TITLE</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="title" size="20"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="hidden" name="do" value="store">
  <input type="submit" value="ADD RECORD"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
  <p align="center"><a href="index.php">Go Back to Home</a></p>
  <?
  include("search.php");?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What are the error messages?? Also...you are vulnerable to SQL injection...

Comment: `if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
  $query="insert into mylibrary value
  ('$isbn','$title')";
  mysql_query($query);` this is not a valid procedural style. First you need to assign value to your variable $query i.e. $query = "SELECT col FROM tbl"; then $query_run = mysql_query($query); and on last place to check is true => if($query_run) { echo 'success' }. In the code u've shown, u are trying to check if $query_run is true, but it still does not have real query in it, and if true, to assign query which is alogical

Comment: please go 100% ajax.  life will be soooooooooooo much better

Comment: [**STOP POSTING THE SAME THING OVER AND OVER !!!!**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039334/insert-php-cannot-link-to-phpmyadmin-when-i-insert-data-it-will-not-display)

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in your `if` statement, where you are using an assignment statement as a boolean, when that is incorrect. You should do this instead

```
...
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
if ($query_run) {
echo"Successfully added.";
}
```

Otherwise the statement will not work.

EDIT:

```
 $connect = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user,$mysql_pass);    
 if (!$connect) die($conn_error);
 mysql_select_db($mysql_db) or die($conn_error);
```

I tried this code in place of yours and it worked. I believe you had a `@` sign instead of a dollar sign a couple times

Comment: the other thing I could think, though I don't think it would make a difference, is adding an 's' to values, though I'm pretty sure the two are interchangeable. You could also separate the connect and select sql statements into variables like I suggested for the others. The change is in my above edited code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a database connection required fields:

```
<?php
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_localhost = "localhost";
$database_localhost = "database";
$username_localhost = "root";
$password_localhost = "yourpass";
$localhost = mysql_pconnect($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```