# insert php cannot link to phpmyadmin , when i insert data , it will not display in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

my question : my insert php cannot save data to phpmyadmin when it enter the details.
localhost:locahost , username:root password:"" databasename:b_database tablename:my_library
tablecolumn:2 contains : isbn(primary key) and title

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Php Code for View, Search, Edit and Delete Record" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Search Library Record</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1><u>Library Database</u></h1></center>
<form name="search" method="post" action="search.php">
<table style=" border:1px solid silver" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="0px"
align="center">
<tr>
<td colspan="3" style="background:#0066FF; color:#FFFFFF; fontsize:
20px">Search</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter Search Keyword</td>
<td><input type="text" name="search" size="40" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Search" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<th><a href="add.php">Add Record</a></th>
<th><a href="del.php">Delete Record</a></th>
<th><a href="del.php">Update Record</a></th>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

add.php

```
<?php
$conn_error = 'Could not connect.';
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_pass = '';
$mysql_db='b_database';

if(!@mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user,$mysql_pass)|| !@mysql_select_db($mysql_db)){
  die($conn_error);

}
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Php Code for View, Search, Edit and Delete Record" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Add Student Record</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1><u>Library Database</u></h1>
</center>
<?
if($_POST["do"]=="store")
{
$isbn=$_POST["isbn"];
$title=$_POST["title"];
if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
  $query="insert into mylibrary value('$isbn','$title')";
  mysql_query($query);
  echo "Successfully store in DATABASE";
  }
  ?>
  <form name="add" method="post" action="add.php">
  <table style=" border:1px solid silver" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0px"
  align="center" border="0">
  <tr>
  <td colspan="4" style="background:#0066FF; color:#FFFFFF; fontsize:
  20px">ADD RECORD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Enter ISBN</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="isbn" size="20"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Enter TITLE</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="title" size="20"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="hidden" name="do" value="store">
  <input type="submit" value="ADD RECORD"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
  <p align="center"><a href="index.php">Go Back to Home</a></p>
  <?
  include("search.php");?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: can u explain why u use this line:  `if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){`

Comment: [**STOP POSTING THE SAME THING OVER AND OVER !!!!**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039256/php-does-not-save-data-to-mysql)

Comment: Hey we have sort the same name! But yea dude, once is enough. Reword or give better info if you're not getting the response you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems. Some of them:

1. Your query string is wrong. You have `VALUE` instead of `VALUES`
2. You assign a query string to `$query` **after** you execute it
3. Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` extension and switch to either [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
4. Validate and sanitize user input
5. Learn and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of interpolating query strings. The latter is a wide open door to sql injections.

Now back to your immediate problem. Try to change this part

```
if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
  $query="insert into mylibrary value('$isbn','$title')";
  mysql_query($query);
  echo "Successfully store in DATABASE";
}
```

to something like this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO mylibrary (isbn, title) VALUES('$isbn', '$title')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result) {
  echo "Successfully stored in DATABASE";
} else {
  echo "Something went wrong: " . mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: it does not work at all, nothing change

Comment: Where is your code that collects isbn and title and submits to `add.php`??? Your `index.php` doesn't have that part.